# What determines the (default) depth of an exception stacktrace?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Assuming the current call stack is rather deep.

Is there a limit to the depth of an exception stacktrace? Or is it 1:1 the depth of the call stack? If so, what other reasons could there be that the stacktrace "ends early"?

EDIT:
See also this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70620353/523144) which provides the concrete context that sparked this one.

EDIT2: Experimentation seems to indicate that the depth is not normally limited. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YTKui

Comment: That's strange. Didn't find anything on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that the entire thing was a misconception on my part.

The StackTrace per se seems to be quasi infinite.

But an **exception** stacktrace only ever captures the stackframes between the position where the exception occurs and the position where it is caught/handled.

Comment: In a release build, it may also omit frames which have been inlined by the JIT compiler.