# Serilog SelfLog produces exception stacktrace that fails to provide the cutial bit of by ending to early

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

Consider an AspNetCore application which uses Serilog as a logging library.

I am getting an exception printed to the SelfLog. From the stacktrace I am guessing that somewhere I am logging an object for which the destructuring fails. So far so good. I would think it to be a trivial matter to locate the offending log call and fix it. E.g. by simply not using destructuring or some such.

Unfortunately I am having trouble pinpointing where exactly the offending log call is made within my application.

The stacktrace ends *just* before the relevant line.

How can I solve this problem? How can I find the call site?

And also is this normal? Do stacktraces normally terminate at the application/library border? Why should they, that makes no sense IMHO.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.ThrowNoInvokeException()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.StructureValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties, String typeTag)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertCompilerGeneratedType(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.DepthLimiter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.StructureValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties, String typeTag)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertCompilerGeneratedType(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.DepthLimiter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.<TryConvertEnumerable>g__MapToSequenceElements|14_1(IEnumerable sequence, Destructuring destructure)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.SequenceValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 elements)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertEnumerable(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.DepthLimiter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.StructureValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties, String typeTag)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertCompilerGeneratedType(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.DepthLimiter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.StructureValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties, String typeTag)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertCompilerGeneratedType(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.DepthLimiter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.<TryConvertEnumerable>g__MapToSequenceElements|14_1(IEnumerable sequence, Destructuring destructure)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.SequenceValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 elements)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertEnumerable(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.DepthLimiter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Serilog.Events.StructureValue..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties, String typeTag)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertCompilerGeneratedType(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Type valueType, LogEventPropertyValue& result)
   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(Object value, Destructuring destructuring, Int32 depth)
   at Serilog.Core.Logger.BindProperty(String propertyName, Object value, Boolean destructureObjects, LogEventProperty& property)
   at Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLogger.Write[TState](LogEventLevel level, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
```

EDIT:
I asked an other question regarding the stacktrace ending "early" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621459/523144). As it turns out that is normal/by design as it is an exception stacktrace and this is where the exception is caught.

EDIT2:
This seems to be specific to https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging, i.e. when using Serilog through the Microsoft Logging Library. I have created a pull request to add a more complete stacktrace. See [#198](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/198).

Comment: is this a debug or release build?

Comment: Ok, as it turns out the stacktrace ending where it does is normal, as it is an exception stacktrace and that is where the exception is caught. 
Which does not help one bit with the core problem, though.

Comment: @sommmen it is a release build. And it only occurs in an integration environment. So the usual debugging approach is difficult.

Comment: i saw your other question - the stacktrace is never limited to a certain depth thats ludicrous, i'm thinking the offending statement is optimized away maybe. This however looks like a bug in the library `   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()` seems to throw something.

w/o knowing the input this is hard to debug tho - any change of a debug build + remote debugging maybe?

Comment: Seems like its trying to destructure an object and failing on accesing the getter via PropertyInfo.GetValue() - do you have any dynamic (expandoobject? dynamic json obj?) like objects perhaps? or getters that might throw a 'not supported'? that last one seems unlikely tho

Comment: @sommmen Yes, something like that. The current suspect is a statement that logs a 3rd party email-error-object. So it may well be that that is somehow so convoluted that it cannot be destructured by Serilog. Which would be fine, if Serilog would just tell me WHICH log statement failed :/.

Comment: i understand what you're getting at but again this seems like a lib bug. try and get a reproducible sample and post to git. And good luck i don't think i can be of more help :')

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about this one specifically, I can only give you a few pointers on how to log and find the cause.

The way I developed fault-tolerant enterprise applications is using **try-catch-finally** with configurable logging levels. With this approach you can turn on or off levels as needed if you are debugging, getting information, or just plain errors.

I use :

- try - to do the logic
- catch - to catch the exception and log it
- finally - to release the resource

If I really wish to go the extra step, I would have extra logging levels:

```cs
  try {
       logger.Info("Info :: I'm doing business call X");
       logger.Debug($"Debug :: I'm using object {foo}, calling foo.logic()");
       
       foo.Logic();
       
       logger.Info("Debug :: Succesfully called foo.logic()");
   }
   catch (Exception exc) {
    logger.Debug($"Error :: Failed business case foo.logic() and object info : {foo}");
    logger.Error($"Error :: Exception {exc}");

   }
   finally {
    foo.CleanUp();
    foo = null;
   }
```

With this approach, I could easily put a few breakpoints, in the catch or finally, and find out what was breaking the application. On top, there is verbose logging to debug.

Comment: The problem in this case is that it is a log statement that fails. I just do not know precisely which one and why. Of cause I can attempt to identify it by looking and perhaps adding *other* log statements. Debugging is also difficult because this happens on an integration environment where debugging is not easily done.  Both of which should not really be necessary if the stacktrace were to be just one line longer ... That is kind of it's entire purpose.